# Why does $('something').length doesn't get updated on this snipped code?

Tags: jquery

```
function showMember() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('member'); ?>',
        data: {
            index: $('#members fieldset').length
        },
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (html) {
            $('#members').append(html);
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    showMember();
    $('.addMember').on('click', function () {
        showMember();
        //length+1 ???
        if ($('#members fieldset').length + 1 > 2) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Why `$('#members fieldset').length` doesn't take into consideration the added fieldsets by the call of `showMember();` upon click?

Is there a way to make `$('#members fieldset').length` to know this, in order to avoid adding that +1 ?

Thanks.

**Update:** Here's the new code based on answers below:

```
$(function() {
   showMember();
   $('.addMember').on('click', function() {
        showMember().done(function() {
            alert('hi there');
            if($('#members fieldset').length > 2) {
              $(this).hide();
            }
        });
   });    
});
```

Doesn't seem to enter on `.done(function`, **no** `alert()` displayed.

Thanks again.

Comment: Because the if-statement is called before the ajax has finished, probably...

Comment: you need to return the `$.ajax({})`

Comment: which element do you want to hide

Comment: the element with the class `.addMember` (but I don't even get the alert(); triggered. So it shouldn't be related with the `this` pointer I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that your code runs after the AJAX request has finished. The easiest way to do so is by returning the promise object and attaching another handler for the success event:

```
function showMember() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('
        member '); ?>',
        data: {
            index: $('#members fieldset').length
        },
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html) {
            $('#members').append(html);
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
    showMember();
    $('.addMember').on('click', function() {
        showMember().done(function() {}
        if($('#members fieldset').length + 1 > 2) {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

The nice thing is that the `done()` callback also receives the same arguments as `success` so if necessary you could access the response there, too.

Comment: Was on my way to post the same, but you beat me to it, hehe =) +1

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I removed the extra `}` and removed the `+ 1` - but now, the $(this).hide(); doesn't hide the button as expected... :s - not sure why. I `alert($('#members fieldset').length);` outside before the showMember(), but not after it... - why ?

Comment: Do note that jQuery no longer recommends `.done()`. See the `async` section in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ And having some logic in `.done()` and some logic in `success` isn't so organized. You should do the `.length` check inside the `success` function.

Comment: @TerryYoung but if I do apply that inside the success function, shouldn't I, again, guarantee that the append finishes ?

Comment: @TerryYoung: It is only discouraged when using `async:false`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Ah, you're right, I stand corrected. Thank you sir.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Can you please check the question update, and update your answer accordingly. For some reason, done() doesn't seem to be triggered.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ahhh! yes it has... hhmmm... thanks. So the done will work based on the returned value of showMember... wondering: Why is that ? Why do we need to make return ?

Answer (score 0):

because your if statement does not wait until your ajax is done. Probably the counting is performed before the html has been added.
Either you put your if function in a setTimeout or you **run the code within the ajax callback, right after you append the html.**

Comment: The setTimeout suggestion is horrible. You cannot know how long the AJAX request takes.

Comment: thats totally right. thats why i suggested to run the code within the callback :)

Answer (score 0):

Other answers beat me to it, but here's just another alternative to offer

```
function showMember() {

    var THIS = this; // <------ note this

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('member'); ?>',
        data: {
            index: $('#members fieldset').length
        },
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (html) {
            $('#members').append(html);
            if ($('#members fieldset').length + 1 > 2) {
                $(THIS).hide();
            }
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    showMember();
    $('.addMember').on('click', function () {
        showMember.apply(this); // <--- and note this
    });
});
```